# Compute columns in SharePoint Designer 2010 AllItems.aspx xslt view

Tags: xml, xslt, sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Could you please help me to implement following:

I have custom list with 3 columns (LinkTitle, Location, Location2).
If column Location2 is empty, it should take values from Location column

I've made following, doesn't work:

```
<xsl:template name="FieldRef_header.Location2" ddwrt:dvt_mode="header" match="FieldRef[@Name='Location2']" mode="header" ddwrt:ghost="hide">
<th nowrap="nowrap" scope="col" onmouseover="OnChildColumn(this)">
  <xsl:attribute name="class">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="@Location2 != ''">
            <xsl:value-of select="@Location2" />
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="@Location" />
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:attribute>
  <xsl:call-template name="dvt_headerfield.Location2">
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldname">
      <xsl:value-of select="@Name"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldtitle">
      <xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="displayname">
      <xsl:value-of select="@DisplayName"/>
    </xsl:with-param>
    <xsl:with-param name="fieldtype">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="@Type='Number' or @Type='Currency'">number</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>x:string</xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:with-param>
  </xsl:call-template>
</th>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it with an additional *Current Location* Column of **Calculated** type, and Formula:

```
=IF( ISBLANK(Location2) , Location , Location2 )
```

That's the SharePoint Way

Comment: The problem is that I have duplicated columns which showing in SP with the same name e.g. Location and Location. But in SP Designer I see the difference between them e.g. Location and Location123.

Comment: So fields in the same list have the same **DisplayName**, Yes that is a No-No for Calculated Columns (and does not help a User either) If you want to make it work in CC then you have to change the DisplayNames